# What does the symbol ^\ mean in linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, escaping

I got a file output from my perl script.

When I use less to open it `less output`
it looks like this: ABCDEFG^\HIJKLMN

When I use cat or head to open it `head output`
it looks like this ABCDEFGHIJKLMN

So I want to ask what is the ^\ symbol?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

This representation is known as "caret notation" and is one notation used by some tools and editors to show undrawable control characters.

`^\` in particular represents the ASCII file separator character, aka "FS" or 0x1C.

You can determine this manually by taking the ASCII value of the backslash (0x5C) and substracting 0x40, giving 0x1C. Should you want to input it in a terminal, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

This character is not used in any meaningful sense today. How it got into your perl script output is anyone's guess.

Comment: Thanks very much! I found a bug in my perl script: instead of `$a{$a1 . $a2} = xxx` I typed `$a{$a1 , $a2} = xxx`, do you know how the replacement of period with comma leads to this error?